# como hacer para bloquear el boton atras del dispositivo en xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarinforms

Hola colegas estoy desarrollando una apk en C# xamarin forms visual studio 2019 y necesito deshabilitar el botón atrás del dispositivo, pero no veo ninguna documentación al respecto que me pueda ayudar, he leído algo del evento OnBackButtonPressed () pero a la verdad no se donde implementarlo, si me pudieran ayudar al respecto, se lo agradeceria, saludos y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

En el *Main Activity Android* sobre el `OnCreate` (es decir, antes de esa función) coloca esto:

```
public override void OnBackPressed() 
{ 
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a asociar un commando al botón. Deberías hacerlo en el propio xaml.

Supongamos que estás usando Prism o tienes creada tu propia clase MyCommand. Te vale cualquier implementación de ICommand:

```
ICommand backCommand = new MyCommand(Execute, CanExecute);

private void Execute()
{
   //lógica del programa para navegación hacia atrás.
}

private bool CanExecute()
{
    return false;
}
```

El método CanExecute será el habilité o deshabilite el botón. Sustituye el return false por la condición que necesites que se cumpla para habilitar/deshabilitar el botón Back